# Issue Calling PHP from HTML

Tags: php, html, scripting

I have written code in php which is like this

```
<a href="http://localhost/contactus.html" title="CONTACT US" > CONTACT US</a>
```

By right, it should go to htaccess file and see if any rewrite is there not.
My .htaccess file is

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html /index.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

so i suppose contactus should be $1 therefore file=contactus
and it should call

```
http://localhost/index.php?file=contactus
```

But its not happening.

I checked htaccess rewrite working fine and enabled.

PLease help.Thanks

Comment: check your apache log file to see what error you are getting

Comment: Also, try enabling the rewritelog so that you can see what is happening in your rewrite rules.  That regex is trying to avoid matching a leading slash, but depending on what you're matching it against (and you don't show us) there may well be a leading slash on every single request...

Comment: First , i run http://localhost/index.php file, in that there is contact us link, i click on that , then it goes to http://localhost/contactus.html.

Comment: Offcourse there is no contactus.html file, therefore it say The page cannot be displayed 
"The page you are looking for is currently unavailable." .. But I expect .haccess rule to be followed, and it should redirect me to http://localhost/index.php?file=contactus

Comment: Dear Sir, please let me know what information more shall i post

Comment: When I checked my Rewrite  logfile seting level to 5 , it says this

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/contactus.html -> contactus.html                          applying pattern '^([^/]+).html' to uri 'contactus.html'   rewrite 'contactus.html' -> '/index.php?file=contactus'                split uri=/index.php?file=contactus -> uri=/index.php, args=file=contactus

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index.php?file=$1 [NC][L]
```

Comment: Sir, I tried your rewrite rule, but i could not bring up http://localhost/index.php file , it says server busy  error. then i tried old rewriterule and it is able to bring up